# Unit Testing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, rhino-mocks

In my controller I want to test if the controller is calling the repository method.
Here is the method in **controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetModulePropertyName(string moduleTypeValue)
{
  var temp = _modulerepository.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(moduleTypeValue);

  IList<Property> model = temp
     .Select(item => new Property {Name = item})
     .ToList();

  return PartialView("GetModulePropertyName",model);
}
```

And here is the **test method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetModulePropertyName_Action_Calls_GetModuleKindPropertyNames()
{
  _mockRepository.Stub(x => x.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));

  _controller.GetModulePropertyName(Arg<string>.Is.Anything);

  _mockRepository.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
}
```

It throws an **error** saying

```
Test method AdminPortal.Tests.ModuleControllerTests.GetModulePropertyName_Action_Calls_GetModuleKindPropertyNames threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at System.Linq.Queryable.Select(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   at AdminPortal.Areas.Hardware.Controllers.ModuleController.GetModulePropertyName(String moduleTypeValue) in ModuleController.cs: line 83
   at AdminPortal.Tests.ModuleControllerTests.GetModulePropertyName_Action_Calls_GetModuleKindPropertyNames() in ModuleControllerTests.cs: line 213
```

I'm using **RhinoMock** as mocking tool.
Can someone help with what mistake i'm making?

Comment: There are correct answers below, but I would argue that you're testing too invasively. Since the method you're testing has a return value, it should be sufficient to write tests that test on what is being returned. So long as you get the correct result back, the details of how the result is achieved doesn't really need tests, and such tests will just add to the maintenance and brittleness of your test harness.

Comment: So you are trying to say that there is no point on checking if the controller methods are calling the repository to get the required data and rendering the proper type of view or not?

Comment: I don't think so. I would write tests that check that the PartialView returned is correct. Beyond that it's unimportant how the underlying code solves it. If there is a lot of logic that needs to happen back there, split it into its own modules and put unit tests around that logic separately. Testing actual method calls is a last resort if there is no other output to test. You want to test your results, not your architecture. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After stubbing the method use `Return` to indicate what should it return, for example:

```
_mockRepository
  .Stub(x => x.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
  .Return(Enumerable.Empty<string>().AsQueryable());
```

Also, change this line:

```
_controller.GetModulePropertyName(Arg<string>.Is.Anything);
```

to this:

```
_controller.GetModulePropertyName(string.Empty);
```

As the exception explains - `Arg` is only to be used in mock definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a return on your stub.

```
_mockRepository.Stub(x => x.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
```

without that return, this line will be running a lambda against a null reference

```
 IList<Property> model = temp.Select(item => new Property {Name = item}).ToList();
```

so:

```
    _mockRepository.Stub(x => x.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return(new Module[]{}); // set some return data here
```